# Trying to get Media Queries to work on Portrait OR Landscape

Tags: html, css

here it is, this is the css, and the media queries is down below, just search @media and it will find it.

Thanks so much for your help, idk why it is not working, the media query has no effect on the ipad emulator, in portrait mode, i changed the background just to see if it would work and it still did not, so not sure whats going on.

```
body {background-image:url('../images/space1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:200%;
}

body {
    color:white;
}

a, a:visited { 
    color:#3399FF; text-decoration:none;
}

div.header{
    text-align:right;
    font-size:200%;
}

div.header1 {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:125%;
}

div.logo{
    margin-top:-40px;
}

#nav{
    width:85%;
    height:3%;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: ;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:120px;
}

#nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: :#3399FF;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFF;

li:hover ul { 
    display: block; 
}

}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

div.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:200%;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

div.specs {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:175%;
}

ul.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.images {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.1 {
  text-align: center;      
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

p.v {
    text-align:center;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

    div.header{
        text-align:right;
        font-size:120%;
    }

    div.header1 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:85%;
    }

    div.logo{
        margin-top:-40px;
    }

    div.logo {
        img
        height:150px;
        width:320px;
}   

    #nav{
        width:85%;
        height:3%;
        font-size: 30%;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: ;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:120px;
    }

    #nav ul {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav li { 
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px; 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: :#3399FF;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    }

    #nav a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFF;

    li:hover ul { 
        display: block; 
    }
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}

div.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:200%;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

div.specs {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:175%;
}

ul.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.images {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.1 {
  text-align: center;      
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left:0%;
  padding:0px;
   border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right:0%;
  padding:0px;
   border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

p.v {
    text-align:center;
}

}
```

Comment: Show the @media-query part.  What you have is simply css, with no media-query aspect to it.

Comment: this is what i am trying now, @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
 but no go still, i changed the background on it in the css just to see if it worked on ipad portrait, and nope.

Comment: Show it in your css.  Edit your question, and show it in the question, otherwise we can't fully troubleshoot / see what you are doing.

Comment: there ya go, sorry about that

Comment: see this article.  I suspect it'll help you figure out what's going on: http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/

Comment: that is exactly the media query i used, copy and pasted it, and added the } at the end of my css

Comment: any idea what im doing wrong? not missing any () or anything it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is primarily twofold:

1) You have several errors in your css.  Using the validator, I found 13 errors.
    - There's declarations that are unclosed (missing a closing curly-brace - `}`), such as your declaration for `#nav a:hover`
    - There's extra / stray closing curly-braces in other locations.
    - There's invalid background color and color properties
    - You have div.1, which implies a class of "1".  That's not a valid class according to the validator.

2) The media query contains far too many rules.  You should *only* put rules in the media query that replace / override previous rules, or are new rules.  You've got many rules that are simply repeats of your other common css rules.

Clean up the errors.  Try running them through the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) - you can copy-and-paste your css directly, to see if / where there are errors.

Then, simplify your media query css to only include the necessary changed rules (and only the specific properties that need to be changed).

Note: I was able to get it to validate by cleaning up the errors.  For your reference, the valid / clean CSS is below.

**You still need to simplify**, and the code below is not necessarily guaranteed to work.  I'd encourage you to over-simplify - put **one** rule in your media query for a border, background color, or something, just to see if the media query is getting picked up.  Then you can work on adding in the different styles you need.

```
body {background-image:url('../images/space1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:200%;
}

body {
    color:white;
}

a, a:visited { 
    color:#3399FF; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

div.header{
    text-align:right;
    font-size:200%;
}

div.header1 {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:125%;
}

div.logo{
    margin-top:-40px;
}

#nav{
    width:85%;
    height:3%;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:120px;
}

#nav ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#3399FF;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

li:hover ul { 
    display: block; 
}


nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

div.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:200%;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

div.specs {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:175%;
}

ul.qui {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.images {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.one {
  text-align: center;      
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right:20%;
    padding:10px;
    border:3px solid #585858 ;
}

p.v {
    text-align:center;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

    div.header{
        text-align:right;
        font-size:120%;
    }

    div.header1 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:85%;
    }

    div.logo{
        margin-top:-40px;
    }

    div.logo {
        height:150px;
        width:320px;
    }   

    #nav{
        width:85%;
        height:3%;
        font-size: 30%;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:120px;
    }

    #nav ul {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav li { 
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px; 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#3399FF;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    }

    #nav a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }

    li:hover ul { 
        display: block; 
    }



 nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
    }

    div.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:200%;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

    div.specs {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:175%;
    }

    ul.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:150%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .images {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .images img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    div.one {
      text-align: center;      
    }

    .left {
      float: left;
      margin-left:0%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    .right {
      float: right;
      margin-right:0%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    p.v {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i just went ahead and cleaned up my css, just so I knew what was wrong myself. I tried the media query stuff you posted, and changing background color, and for some reason it will not work. I am using ipadpeek.com and testing  the url http://darthvixcustomsabers.com/ascend.html

Comment: @Terry - CSS still not valid.  You can test it from the url.  Here's the results I got: [Test by URI](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdarthvixcustomsabers.com%2Fstyle%2Fascend.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Comment: thanks, I got it to affect the ipad portrait, only 1 question, is it possible to align my nav bar centered, with an easy command, instead of playing with margins till it looks centered? text-align:centered; doesnt seem to actually center it

Comment: ok but now the landscape one has no effect, ug the (orientation : landscape) maybe doesnt work on emulator? hmm